# Triggering style changes using data- attributes

Tags: html, css

I am developing a UI framework and to be able to trigger style changes in HTML elements, I am using the following technique in several cases. I was wondering if this practice is common amongst frontend developers, for example:

```css
[data-layout=fitted] {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}

[data-layout=center] {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
      top: 50%;
    left:50%;
    @include transform(translate(-50%,-50%));
}
```

And the HTML

```html
<div class="some-class" data-layout="center">centered within parent element</div>

<div class="some-class" data-layout="fitted">fitted into parent element</div>
```

BTW: my work is to be found [here :)](https://github.com/blendsdk/blendsdk/tree/poc-ui)

Comment: Yes it's common to use ids, classes and custom attributes to style elements.

Answer (score -2):

Try to put element tag before data attributes

```
div[data-layout="fitted"] {
width:100%;
height:100%;
display: block;
position: relative;
top:0;
left:0;
padding:0;
margin:0;
}
```

Comment: Can you prove that "you must" prefix the attribute selector with the element?

Comment: And if I want to use the directive on another element type?

Comment: if you want to use it you can use comma "," between classes like 
div[data-layout="fitted"],div[data-layout="center"],div[data-layout="top"]
{
   width:100%;
   height:100%;
   display: block;
   position: relative;
}